# Modal closes when opening an accordion - Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have come across an issue now I have uploaded my site.

I have multiple buttons that open modals and some of these modals have accordions to keep the content tidy and uncluttered.

Whilst just running the HTML file locally there was no issue but now it is running on the site when I open an accordion within a modal the modal closes. I presume this is because the collapse is being toggled on both elements ie the accordion opens but the modal closes.

Is there a relatively simple way of solving this? There are possibly 30 different modals and buttons and even more accordions obviously all with different IDs.

One solution I found was to tell a modal to stay open when an accordion was opened. But this would mean writing quite a lot of JS to do this for every modal and accordion!

An example of my Modal and accordion is below,

```
//Button image to open a modal
<div class="col-xs-8 col-md-4 mb-3">
                <div class="portfolio-item mx-auto" data-target="#ICSkin" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="portfolio-item-caption d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100 w-100">
                        <div class="portfolio-item-caption-content text-center text-white">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                    <img alt="skin" class="img-fluid" src="image.png"/>
                    <p class="text-center">Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>


//Modal content
<!-- Intermediate Care Skin section-->
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="SkinLabel" class="portfolio-modal modal fade " id="ICSkin" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-times">&nbsp;</i></span>
            </button>
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <!-- Portfolio Modal - Title-->
                            <h2>Title</h2>
                            <!--Bites-->
                            <div class="text-left" id="bitesSection">
                                <h2 class="text-center" id="bites">Human and Animal Bites</h2>
                                //Some text
                                <!--Start accordian-->
                                <div id="accordionBites">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-header" id="bitesTreatment">
                                            <h5 class="mb-0"><button aria-controls="collapseBitesTreatment" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-target="#collapseBitesTreatment" data-toggle="collapse">Treatment</button></h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div aria-labelledby="bitesTreatment" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordionBites" id="collapseBitesTreatment">
                                            <div class="card-body text-left">
                              //Some text
                                                
                              </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I open a modal clicking on the button it opens fine, But if I click to expand the accordion the modal closes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with this. I found it odd it closed the modal when live on the site but not on my local machine. I couldn't find anything to give a reason for this behaviour so I uploaded the page to my own website and it worked fine. It turns out the site I am using it on has some other js which overrides my page and so that code is causing the modal to close.